# Bootable Drive Problem

Tags: bootable-disk, downgrade

I've followed [this guide](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/bootable-mac-installer-3575875/#createinstall) on creating a bootable drive to downgrade from Big Sur for MacOS Catalina.

- I bought a new flash drive, plugged it in and erased it.
- I set the SanDisk Cruzer Blade Media to a GUID Partition map,
- I then created the volume and set it as MAC OS Extended (Journal),
- I run the commands in terminal and it copies the Catalina over fine, says complete.
- I restart my Mac and select the Install Mojave drive (Not my MACINTOSH HD)
- In disk utility I select to install Catalina
- Click continue on the installation
- Then only the bootable drive appears, but says "This disk is locked"
- I've also tried to use the System Preferences -> Start Up Disc but all I can see it the original Mac HD and not the bootable drive.

I can only open my Mac in Safe Mode will this have something to do with?

How can I get past this problem?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Specifically which Mac? Assuming it will run Mojave or Catalina [your question isn't really clear on why you're installing Mojave to get to Catalina] then you'll first have to erase the entire internal drive.

Comment: Macbook Air 2014, I installed Big Sur last week and haven't been able to open the OS fully since (nothing to with Mojave that's my error when typing)

Comment: If you can boot from the USB key (push alt key at boot), the first thing to do is open Disk Utility, then select the physical internal ssd (cmd+2 if not listed) then select Erase :Partition scheme : GUID format : apfs then accept. Quit disk utility and install Catalina.

Comment: "This disk is locked" could be related to FileVault being active on the Volume. Open disk utility first and mount the volume (enter you password when prompted), close disk utility and select Install.

Comment: Can you try to rewrite your question? There are a few things that don't really add up. Why do you have a Volume that is called "Install Mojave"? What do you mean by you select install Catalina in disk utility, you don't start the installation in disk utility after all..